# Parsing an equation using parboiled and applying to values

Tags: java, parsing, parboiled

I need to parse an equation and then apply it to values. For example, I would like to parse

```
(x+4)*y
```

and then apply it to an array of values for x and y. I am able to use the calculator example to evaluate individual equations like

```
(3+4)*5
```

but I am not sure how to make this generic. I am using Parboiled for Java. Any direction would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, can I ask that you open an example grammar for this at https://github.com/parboiled1/parboiled-examples? It will be interesting!

Comment: @fge I actually solved this problem. While parsing, I saved the structure of the nodes. Then on reuse, I just populate the base nodes and walk through the tree to re-calculate. Saves about 70% of time if I do not have to parse again. Let me know if you would still like me to do something. I can also write the pseudo-code in an answer here if you would like. Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind submit a pull request to -examples with your code? It'd be great!

Comment: @fge Embarrassed to say that I have never done a pull before. Happy to share my thoughts. I can even envision how to put it into the initial calc example. But, any help on how to pull, edit and submit back would be great. Cheers

Comment: Can you [join this SO chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java)?

Comment: Or you can join channel #parboiled1 on IRC (freenode, irc.freenode.net)

Comment: I'm interested in that in -memory AST you used for re-applying in turn to each row (and avoid the overhead of re-paring / regenerating new parse tree). Did you get that code submitted to @fge?